# Ayuda con PHP Simple HTML DOM

Tags: php

Estoy trabajando con un sitio en donde el usuario quiere tener un listado de sus pruductos publicados en mercado libre uruguay.
Los productos estan en una base de datos asi:

urlcomp.sql

```
uid | urlu
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   | https://articulo.mercadolibre.com.uy/MLU-471804196-campera-rusty-newport-la-isla-_JM
2   | https://articulo.mercadolibre.com.uy/MLU-471804204-campera-rusty-truman-la-isla-_JM
```

Este es el script - **ACTUALIZADO**

```
<?php

try {
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tienda', 'root', '');
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "ERROR: " . $e->getMessage();
}
//date_default_timezone_set('America/Montevideo');

require 'simple_html_dom.php';


while ($row = $list->fetch()) {
$url = $row['urlu'];

$html = file_get_html($url);

$titulo = $html->find('header[class=item-title]',0);
$resp = $titulo->find('h1[class=item-title__primary]',0);

echo $resp.'<br>';
$img = $html->find('img',3);
echo $img->outertext.'<br>';

}

?>
```

El problema es que no me lista los titulos para poder linkearlos y solo me muestra el ultimo producto agregado a la base de datos.

Otro problema que tengo es que me muestra todas las imagenes y solo necesito uno, ya que el usuario iria directamente a mercadolibre a ver dicho producto.

Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que dentro del `while` estás sobre-escribiendo la variable `$html`, para obtener todos los datos deberías **concatenar**.

```
#Creamos la variable aquí vacía
$html="";

while ($row = $list->fetch()) {
    $url = $row['urlu'];
    #Concatenamos con .=  
    // Create DOM from URL or file
    $html.=file_get_html($url);
}
#Resto del código
```

En cuanto a la imagen, si sólo quieres la primera, en vez de un ciclo `foreach` buscas directamente la primera:

```
$img=$html->find('img',0);
echo $img->outertext . '<br>';
```

Comment: Gracias Cedano, pero tengo este error: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function find() on string in`. Voy a actualizar los cambios que hice

Comment: Ahi lo actualice y funciona, no porque ni porque, pero funciona. Puedo preguntarte como puedo insertar la imagen en una etiqueta `img` para poder cambiar el tamaño de las mismas?

Comment: @Apolo no entiendo tu última duda. ¿Te refieres a una URL de la imagen?

Comment: Si si, gracias Cedano, pude resolverlo, a la imagen le faltaba el atributo `src`. `$img = $html->find('img',0)->attr['src'];`, de esta forma puede usar la etiqueta `img` y cambiar el tamaño. Muchas gracias!